# Image with srcset and sizes attributes load the big image

Tags: image, size, srcset

I have the same image in 3 different sizes that i would to optimize according to the viewport and the DPR (pixel density ratio) of the device.

To do so, I have the following:

```
<img src="${item.imageUrl}" alt="${item.alt!!}"
srcset="'/static/img/common/testImg/500.jpg' 500w,
        '/static/img/common/testImg/1000.jpg' 1000w,
        '/static/img/common/testImg/1500.jpg' 1500w"

sizes="(min-width: 500px) 1500px, (min-width: 900px) 1000px, 500w">
```

What I want to achieve:

- from 0px   to 500px => I would like to display the 500.jpg
- from 500px to 900px => I would like to display the 1500.jpg
- from 900px to XXXX  => I would like to display the 1000.jpg

The issue:
If i'm loading the page after 900px wide, the 1500.jpg img is loaded.
By the way, i have clear my cash, DPR is 1 and here is my viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
```

Thanks

Comment: the size attribute of the image element tells the browser how much the image takes up vw on the specific media conditions
 sizes="(media-query) current-img-size vw" 
for example let's say in 500px your image takes up 80vw and in 900px takes 50vw
   sizes="(min-width: 500px) 80vw, (min-width: 900px) 50vw, 500w">

Answer (score 2):

According to W3Schools.com this should work :

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width:500px)" srcset="/static/img/common/testImg/500.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width:1000px)" srcset="/static/img/common/testImg/1000.jpg">
   <source media="(min-width:1500px)" srcset="/static/img/common/testImg/1500.jpg">
   <img src="/static/img/common/testImg/500.jpg" alt="image" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

If you are interested you can find out more here : [W3Schools source srcset Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp)

Comment: Unfortunatly, I need to use the html img tag for SEO performance. If i'm not able to perform what i'm looking, i will fallback to this solution

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember where but I saw that only the first matched madia query is used by browsers. You should try with

```html
<img src="${item.imageUrl}" alt="${item.alt!!}"
  srcset="'/static/img/common/testImg/500.jpg' 500w,
          '/static/img/common/testImg/1000.jpg' 1000w,
          '/static/img/common/testImg/1500.jpg' 1500w"
  sizes="(min-width: 900px) 1000px, (min-width: 500px) 1500px, 500px">
```

(PS: you used a bad unit for the fallback size, `w` instead of `px`)

Remember that browsers will use every sources as they want. With a high display screen, a browser can use `1000.jpg` for the 500px wide image, to render the image in a better quality.

Comment: Even if i put 500px, this isn't working properly. If i'm loading the page after 900px wide, the 1500.jpg img is loaded. I need the 1000.jpg to load. Why is this happening?

Comment: As I said, if the browser wants to show an image with more density, he will use a bigger image. To show want I say look at this https://i.postimg.cc/5295fF9z/images.png
It's the same code every time and the same viewport, on the left it's with 1x density, the rendered image is the 500, on the middle we have a 2x density, the image used is 1000, on the right it's a 3x density and the browser use 1500px wide image

Comment: If i load the page at 905px wide, i would like to display the 1000.jpg with a DPR 1. Currently, the 1500.jpg is loaded :(